# ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Below is the code I have written:

```
X2=df['title']
y2=df['news_type']
X2_train, X2_test, y2_train, y2_test = train_test_split(X2, y2, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
pp=Pipeline([
    ('bow',CountVectorizer(analyzer=final)),
    ('tfidf',TfidfTransformer()),
    ('classifier',RandomForestClassifier())
    ])
pp.fit(X2_train.astype("U"),y2_train.astype("U"))
predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-300-2bed28a1314e> in <module>
----> 1 predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test)

/home/monika/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    117 
    118         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 119         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    120         # update the docstring of the returned function
    121         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

/home/monika/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    405         Xt = X
    406         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 407             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    408         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    409 

/home/monika/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in transform(self, raw_documents)
   1248 
   1249         # use the same matrix-building strategy as fit_transform
-> 1250         _, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, fixed_vocab=True)
   1251         if self.binary:
   1252             X.data.fill(1)

/home/monika/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1108         for doc in raw_documents:
   1109             feature_counter = {}
-> 1110             for feature in analyze(doc):
   1111                 try:
   1112                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

/home/monika/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _analyze(doc, analyzer, tokenizer, ngrams, preprocessor, decoder, stop_words)
     97 
     98     if decoder is not None:
---> 99         doc = decoder(doc)
    100     if analyzer is not None:
    101         doc = analyzer(doc)

/home/monika/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in decode(self, doc)
    217 
    218         if doc is np.nan:
--> 219             raise ValueError("np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or "
    220                              "unicode string.")
    221 

ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

## Tried everything to resolve this error but couldnot solve it. Please tell what have I done wrong here ?
Its throwing error only after this line :predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test). I have pasted the error above.

Solution:

```
.Replace "pp.fit(X2_train.astype("U"),y2_train.astype("U"))" by
"pp.fit((X2_train.astype("U").str.lower()),(y2_train.astype("U").str.lower()))"

Replace "predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test)" by "predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test.astype("U"))"
```

Comment: Apparently your input contains `NaN` values. Have you checked `X2_test` for invalid values?

Comment: @G.Anderson How to check that ? Can we remove those invalid values? I dont know how to do this . :((

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Then It throws ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [863, 940] after 3rd line of code

Comment: Try `df = df.fillna('')`

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel This worked for me thanks. I suspect this would also have worked for the OP too. I just put it in `train_test_split(foo['bar'].fillna(''), labels)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Replace "pp.fit(X2_train.astype("U"),y2_train.astype("U"))" by
"pp.fit((X2_train.astype("U").str.lower()),(y2_train.astype("U").str.lower()))"

Replace "predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test)" by "predictions7=pp.predict(X2_test.astype("U"))"
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who have this problem in future. It's most likely as `@Prayson W. Daniel` pointed out that you have `NaN` values in your dataset.

You can either rewrite the whole dataset as `@Prayson W. Daniel` suggested with

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

Or you can apply it downstream when you create your test/train datasets, for example if you only have NaN's in your X column, you can use something like:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    foo['bar'].fillna('no text'), labels,
    test_size=0.30,
    random_state=53
)
```